# Why am I getting -3 shouldn't I be getting +7

Tags: java, bit-manipulation

So I'm doing this and I thought it was going to give me +7 but its giving me -3.

```
public class BitManipulation{
  public static void main (String[] args){
    System.out.println(~2 | 5 >> ((2 & 2)));
  }
}
```

Comment: Why do you think you should get 7?

Comment: Hint: instead of printing the result of the final operation; why don't you print the result of each "sub operation" that takes place? Or run it in a debugger? And when you have done that; and you don't understand why 2 & 2 is giving the result it is giving .. or so; then maybe that makes up a question. But so far, you only wrote: "please tell me how to decompose that simple little expression here".

Comment: -3 is the most reasonable result. -1 if you get the operator precedence wrong. 7 makes no sense at all as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 4):

2 & 2 is 2.

So then you have 5 >> 2 which gives 1 (5 in binary is 101)

So we remain with `~2 | 1`

~2 is inverting all the bits. For 8 binary digits (the same goes for 32 but let's keep things concise...) the bits inversion of 00000010 (2) is 11111101. Or-ing this with 1 doesn't change anything.

Now, 11111101 - when treated as a number it is interpreted in two's complement. In this system the most significant bit is the sign, and here it's 1 so the number is negative. To get the absolute value of the number in two's complement we need to invert the bits and add 1.

So inverting 11111101 gives 00000010, and adding 1 gives 00000011, which is 3. Recall the sign was minus, so there you have -3!!! :-)

Answer (score 2):

Try printing off each step like so:

```
System.out.println(2 & 2);
```

You will learn that 2 & 2 = 2 (we are performing the bitwise "AND" function on two binary numbers => 0010 AND 0010 = 0010 which is 2), so plug that into the next step:

```
System.out.println(5 >> 2);
```

Now you have 5 >> 2 = 1 (we are shifting that binary number to the right padding with zeroes because the number is positive, so 0101 becomes 0001 or 1), and plug that into the final step:

```
System.out.println(~2 | 1);
```

And you get ~2 | 1 = -3 (we are performing a bitwise "NOT" followed by a bitwise "OR" operation so 0010 becomes 1101 I believe this is also where it becomes negative and -1101 OR 0001 gives us -1101 or -3)